# C++ Calculator always returns 7208640

Tags: c++, math, calculation

This is the code for my calculator:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int fNumber, sNumber, sum;
    string op;
    cout << "You will be asked for two numbers and the operator to use on them.\nCurrently supported operators are:\n";
    cout << "    Addition: +\n    Subtraction: -\n    Multiplication: *\n    Division: \\\n    Modulo: %\n\n";

    cout << "First Number: ";
    cin >> fNumber;
    cout << "\nSecond Number: ";
    cin >> sNumber;
    cout << "\nOperator: ";
    cin >> op;

    if(op == "+"){
        int sum = fNumber + sNumber;
    } else if(op == "x" || op == "*"){
        int sum = fNumber * sNumber;
    } else if(op == "/"){
        int sum = fNumber / sNumber;
    } else if(op == "-"){
        int sum = fNumber - sNumber;
    } else if(op == "%"){
        int sum = fNumber % sNumber;
    } else{
        cout << "\nPlease use a correct Operator\n";
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "\n" << fNumber << " " << op << " " << sNumber << " = " << sum << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I have absolutely no idea why, but for some reason, whatever numbers or operators I give it it returns "7208640" as the answer:

> You will be asked for two numbers and the operator to use on them.
>
> Currently supported operators are:
>
> Addition: +
>
> Subtraction: -
>
> Multiplication: *
>
> Division: \
>
> Modulo: %
>
> First Number: 6
>
> Second Number: 2
>
> Operator: /
>
> 6 / 2 = 7208640
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 4.612 s Press any key to
>   continue.

Comment: The local variable you create in each of the scopes shadows the one declared at function scope. You're effectively assinging to a variable that's destroyed right away. Your compiler should've warned you about this.

Comment: Dear teachers of new C/C++ students:  Please teach them to enable warnings and teach them what those warnings mean.  It saves so much hassle.  Thank you.

Comment: i always think that the default compiler options should be -wall -werror (or whatever equivalent). This will help new coders enormously. Experienced ones will know how to turn these options off

Comment: except, of course , really experienced ones know to have these options on always :-)

Comment: @pm100 what do those options do? Also, how can I enable these in codeblocks?

Comment: thes are gcc options. -wall means issue all warnings. Some warnings are off by default in many compilers. -werror means treat warnings as errors. Read the docs - i have never used codeblocks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(op == "+"){
    int sum = fNumber + sNumber;
```

should be

```
if(op == "+"){
    sum = fNumber + sNumber;
```

and the same for all the other `int sum` except the first. You declare a variable once, not every time you use it.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the stupid mistake, I only started learning C++ today

Answer (score 2):

As above, remove the int declarations from inside the if statements.

Also, please change the name of the sum variable to something like "answer." A result from subtraction, multiplication, division and modulo is referred to as difference, product, quotient, and remainder, respectively.

Comment: Thank you, hadn't thought that one through!